# Is canonical SOP/POS form for a boolean expression unique?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was trying to find equivalence between two boolean expressions and thought if I convert both of them to **canonical** sum of product or product of sum form they should match. But I am not sure if these forms are unique for a boolean expression, are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "canonical" sum of products and canonical product of sums are unique for a boolean expression, and hence can be used for checking the equivalence of two boolean expressions.

Reference:[Switching Theory for Logic Synthesis By Tsutomu Sasao](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CAL3BwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA42&ots=tqlO8UJLaN&dq=canonical%20sop%20is%20unique&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q=canonical%20sop%20is%20unique&f=false)